# Filter Object list with map key value , replace the Map value

Tags: java

I have a List of Objects

```
List<Person> personLst = [{"person:" {personName:AASH_01 , country :AUS, state :ADL, zip :null }, 
                {personName:AASH_01 , country :AUS, state :MLB, zip :null}}]
```

and Map holds a key value and based on this need to apply the filter for the list.

```
Map<String, String> lstMap = new HashMap<>();
lstMap.put("ADL","12345")
```

**Apply Filter Condition:**
If the `personLst.contains(ADL)` this is a map key filter it and replace the zip with map value`(12345)`.

Tried different stackoverflow question , did not help much on .

Comment: Please show your `Person` class.

Comment: Its a pojo class with getter and setters.

Comment: That doesn't help.  Please show the class.  Especially the fields and the getters and setters.  Please check out [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure,

```
List<Person> personLst = [{"person:" {personName:AASH_01 , country :AUS, state :ADL, zip :null },{personName:AASH_01 , country :AUS, state :MLB, zip :null}}]
```

really refers to a list of valid java objects, right? Because in the current state those would be valid JavaScript Objects, but not valid Java objects.

Also, should a `List<Person>` really be called with `personLst.contains(String)`?

So, assuming these are valid Java objects with the correct getters and setters, and the correct method is intended, you should be able to use

```
personLst.forEach(p -> {
if(lstMap.containsKey(p.getState()))
p.setZip(lstMap.get(p.getState()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks delvh , yes the personLst refers to a valid java objects.